# How to install Python Catalyst on Python 3.7, getting error?

Tags: python, catalyst

```
(catalyst) C:\Users\deliseev\Documents\Pyhon>pip install enigma-catalyst matplotlib
Collecting enigma-catalyst
  Using cached enigma-catalyst-0.5.21.tar.gz (767 kB)
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl (9.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: pip>=7.1.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\envs\catalyst\lib\site-packages (from enigma-catalyst) (20.0.2)
Collecting setuptools==38.5.1
  Using cached setuptools-38.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (489 kB)
Collecting Logbook==0.12.5
  Using cached Logbook-0.12.5.tar.gz (166 kB)
    **ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\catalyst\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\deliseev\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3jmpw5h7\\Logbook\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\deliseev\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3jmpw5h7\\Logbook\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\deliseev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jmpw5h7\Logbook\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\deliseev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jmpw5h7\Logbook\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\deliseev\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3jmpw5h7\Logbook\setup.py", line 57, in <module>
        from setuptools import setup, Extension, Feature
    ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.**
```

as i can see from error, its some issue with setuptools, but is successfully istalled in pevios lines
            from setuptools import setup, Extension, Feature
        ImportError: cannot import name 'Feature'

```
(base) C:\Users\deliseev>python --version
Python 3.7.6
```

Comment: Changed version of Python to 3.6.10 - the same result

Answer (score 0):

Managed to change version of setuptools, the restart

```
pip3 install setuptools==45
pip install enigma-catalyst matplotlib
```

The problem was described here
https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/2017